# Prune Apple Messages Chat

Tags: messages, ichat

My Apple Messages has way, way too many people in it. I'd like to remove the chat sessions that have been dead for more than 6 months. It seems that I should be able to do this by deleting records from `$HOME/Library/Messages.chat.db`, an SQLite3 database, but I haven't figured out how the database works. Has anyone created a program to prune this?